# How to change a view when another view is pressed/clicked

Tags: android, button

If i had `Button btn1` and i had another `Button btn2`
how to connect the two views on the same events like onPress, onFocus.

let me explain:

when i press `btn1` now the `btn1` is pressed and colored with orange background
while am pressing it, i wanna change `btn2` state to be pressed and with background color orange.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a touch listener for Button1 where you can call `Button2.setPressed(true)` after checking the action of the event . i.e if you want it to be pressed only while Button1 is pressed you would call the function when Action is `ACTION_DOWN` and call it again with a false parameter when the Action is `ACTION_UP`. If you want button2 to remain pressed you can use the onClicklistener instead

Answer (score 0):

Call manually `performClick()` (or similar method) of `btn2` in the `onPress()` or `onFocus()` listeners of `btn1`.

Comment: i dont want to pass the click event to `btn2` i just want to pass the focus or the press to change UI

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. In case of `performClick()` it isn't needed to pass the event. Just call of `btn2.performClick()`

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want the click event to be passed to btn2, do a `btn2.callOnClick` instead. It will call any `onClick` action listener associated with `btn2`. If there aren't any, it'll return false.