# How to force a view to redraw immediately before saving it as an image

Tags: android, view, redraw

I have a custom `TextView` that I am treating like an `EditText` view. The user presses a Share button and the layout containing the `TextView` is saved as a PNG image and shared to social networks.

My problem is that the `TextView` has a cursor character in it. Before I create the image I want to remove the cursor character. However, if I remove the character in the same method that I create and share the image, the app crashes because it didn't get a chance to redraw the view first.

My question is basically the same as [How to force a view to redraw immediately before the next line of code is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754709/how-to-force-a-view-to-redraw-immediately-before-the-next-line-of-code-is-execut), but unlike this question I don't need to change background resources.

I tried calling `invalidate()`, but that doesn't solve the problem because the UI never gets a chance to redraw before I need the view.

What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
public void shareToOtherApps(View v) {

    RelativeLayout messageOutline = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMessageOutline);

    // Remove cursor from display (inputWindow is a TextView)
    inputWindow.setText(converter
            .unicodeToFontReadable(unicodeText.toString()));
    inputWindow.invalidate(); // This line makes no difference

    // Code to save image
    messageOutline.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = messageOutline.getDrawingCache(true);
    ...

    // Code to share image
    ...

    // Add cursor back to display
    updateDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but putting the code to save/share the image inside of a `runnable` and running it after removing the cursor character. This puts the `runnable` code at the end of the message stack and allows the UI to update its view before trying to save an image of the view.

Here is the code summary:

```
public void shareToOtherApps(View v) {

    // Remove cursor from display (inputWindow is a TextView)
    inputWindow.setText(converter.unicodeToFontReadable(unicodeText.toString()));

    // Put this in a runnable to allow UI to update itself first
    inputWindow.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Code to save image
            RelativeLayout messageOutline = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMessageOutline);
            messageOutline.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = messageOutline.getDrawingCache(true);

            // Code to share image
            ...

            // Add cursor back to display
            updateDisplay();
        }
    });

}
```